# ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql); not working

Tags: java

i use this program with jdk1.7 and java 64bit and ms access database but the problem i cannot get any result after execute the program , after checking i see the (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);) not work while i can get (sql) value but cannot get (rs)
note: i did all steps to connect the file with ODBC(64-bit).

```
package package1;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
public class Authentication
{
Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;
JFrame f = new JFrame("User Login");
JLabel l = new JLabel("Username");
JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Password");
JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
JPasswordField t1 = new JPasswordField(10);
JButton b = new JButton("Login");
public Authentication()
{
connect();
frame();
}
public void connect()
{


final String fileName = "c:/db2.accdb";
Connection con = null;
try
{  
String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
Class.forName(driver);
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver *.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ="+fileName;
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
}
public void frame()
{ 
f.setSize(400, 100);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setVisible(true);
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.add(l);
p.add(t);
p.add(l1);
p.add(t1);
p.add(b);
f.add(p);
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
try
{
String user = t.getText().trim();
//String pass = t1.getText().trim();
String pass = new String(t1.getPassword());
//String sql = "select user, pass from UserPass where user='"+user+"'and pass = '"+pass+"'";
String sql="SELECT user,pass FROM ADB1 WHERE user = '"+user+"' and pass = '"+pass+"'";
System.out.println(sql);

ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

System.out.println("rs"+rs);
int count = 0;
while(rs.next())
{
count = count +1;
}
if(count == 1)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " You have successfully logged in!");
f.setVisible(false);

}
else if (count > 1)
 {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate User, Access Denied! Please contact    administrator.");
}
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and password is incorrect. Please try to enter your username and password.");
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
}
}); 
}

}
```

Comment: Then your query is not returning anything.  Also, please use parameters instead of literals in your query.

Comment: pls can u tell me what is the difference and how can i use it

Comment: i found the problem , i didnt put this line st = con.createStatement();